# Conference Calling in Pjsua android

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

How to implement Conference calling with pjsip android? 
I can put my current call on hold and un-hold it successfully. Anybody pls do help with conferencing. It seemed to be a tough nut for me. I know, we can start transmitting various ports using startTransmit() in Audio Media. But, firstly, how to initiate a conference call? anybody pls help.

Answer (score 1):

In your code in the handleMediaStateChange of the class that extends Call, look for this line (or something similar)

```
remoteAudio = AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(media);
remoteAudio.startTransmit(audDevManager.getCaptureDevMedia());
```

Make sure that remoteAudio is a class variable and not a local variable.

Configure both calls as if they were single calls. The behavior now should be that you can hear both parties, both parties can hear you, but the 2 parties can't hear each other. To fix this add the following code.

```
call1.remoteAudio.startTransmit(call2.remoteAudio);
call2.remoteAudio.startTransmit(call1.remoteAudio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't `Conference calls` using `PJSIP Android` according to their documentation. See [What is missing](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android) section.

You can contribute as it is open source.

Comment: I am not talking about this pjsip git. I compiled pjsua api, and it is completely built from bottom to top. Now, let A be my voip app, A calls another party B, then calls C, among which A can hear both B, C . Both, B,C can hear A. But, B and C cant hear each other.

Comment: Jakir please read this pdf. It's possible using PJSIP android.https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/PJSUA2Doc.pdf